# Jmeter Performance Thread setup generating with a controlled request

Tags: api, rest, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I'm planning to run my performance test with 100 users for 30 minutes, I noticed it generates bunch of request almost (2M) upon checking the result, is there's a way I could simulate 100 request/per seconds at end of the execution I'm only expecting 180,000 requests. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you

Expectation Request:

Per seconds = 100

Per Minute = 6,000

30 Minutes = 180,000

Thread Setup:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup is kicking off 100 users which are active for 30 minutes and they're executing samplers as **fast as they can**

If you need to slow down the requests execution rate to the given number of requests per second you can consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) to limit JMeter's samplers execution rate to the desired value.

[image]

You can install Throughput Shaping Timer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

JMeter's built-in alternatives are [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) and [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)